# About `dd` onto USB stick if it's not empty

Tags: dd

Should I clean my USB device right before using `dd` to it, in case I'm copying a file with a size lower than the USB capacity?

For example:
my USB stick is 32 GB full of data,
my `.iso` file is 4 GB.

After `dd`ing to the drive, will all the data be erased and overwritten? Or will only 4 GB of data be overwritten with the `.iso` file?

Comment: If you **dd** an iso image to the device (which is correct, rather than a partition), then the old partition table and any filesystem metadata will be lost.  Whatever was previously on that flash drive may not be overwritten, but it will no longer be accessible (by any conventional method).  There's no need to clean or prepare the flash drive.  BTW that iso image had better be a hybrid iso image to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

In your example `dd` will write 4 GB, the rest of your USB stick will not change. It doesn't mean the data there will be easily accessible though.

You write about `.iso` file but I will use the general term "disk image".

The old partition table will be overwritten with something new. If the image is sane, it doesn't contain structures (like a partition table or filesystem header) that point beyond the image itself. After you place it on your USB stick your OS has no reason nor clue to snoop around in what now appears as the unused part of the drive.

If, on the other hand, the image contains a partition table that says there is a partition far far away beyond the image (e.g. the image used to be larger but it was cropped), and by accident there was a partition at the same place, this old partition will be accessible after `dd`ing.

There are programs made to snoop around: forensics and recovery tools. When properly used, they can find old files or even entire filesystems in this leftover space after your `dd`ing.

> Should I clean my USB device?

It depends. If you're afraid the non-overwritten data will interfere with the newly written content, then the answer is: no, because it won't interfere, unless the image is somewhat invalid.

But if you're afraid somebody will get to (some of) your old files, then yes, you should explicitly overwrite the entire capacity of your USB stick; `dd`ing a smaller image is not enough.

The easy way to do this is to write zeros. Overwriting the entire device before `dd`ing the image is a waste of time and write cycles. I would do:

```
cat my_image /dev/zero | sudo dd of=/dev/my_usb
```

This way you will write the image followed by zeros. You will eventually get something like "no space left on device", it's OK.